# Third party library error when applying config transform

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, app-config, config-transformation

I have a C# console application with a number of settings and connection strings.
My goal is to have different values of connection string and app settings for each environment (QA, UAT, PROD, etc.). I know that the best way to do this is adding configuration transformation files. When I added App.QA.config file to my application with just one line of transformation

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="QASQLServer" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I cannot build any more because of error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in XXX.ServiceFramework.dll Additional information: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Common.Logging.Core, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I'm removing App.QA.config - I still can build and run my application